# Django Choice Field default based on index of queryset

Tags: django

Good day SO.

I would like to set my select option default of index 0.

This is how I create my form:

```
SOME_CHOICES = []

someObj = SomeModel.objects.filter(type = 1, is_active=True).order_by('id')
for x in enumerate(someObj):
    SOME_CHOICES.append([x.id, x.salary_range_name])


some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
```

As you can see, I create my choices based on model with filter type of 1. I would like to have the default of the option as the first/index 0

Comment: Manually setting the options that come from a model is often not a good idea. Typically a [**`ModelChoiceField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is used.

Answer (score 1):

Manually setting the options that come from a model is often not a good idea. Typically a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is used.

You can set the `empty_label` to `None` to disable it, so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.filter(type=1, is_active=True).order_by('pk'),
        empty_label=None
    )
```

Comment: Does this, on render, set the first option as default/selected? Sorry. My example was based on what I saw from other answer that worked first for me.

Comment: @rodjames: If I run this locally, the first option is selected yes.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this out.

Comment: I added modelchoicefield. if I remove empty_label, there is this ------- at the top so I know the modelchoicefield is working. However, when I render the template, the first choice is not selected/on default.

Comment: @rodjames: but you need to use `empty_label=None`, since that *disables* the empty field.

Comment: Hello. How do use this on my view? I am expecting an ID but got the Model instead.

`Field 'id' expected a number but got <Something: SomeData>.`
On Select Option:
`<option value="4">SomeData</option>`

Comment: @rodjames: `form.cleaned_data['some_field'].pk`?